# Live streaming video in HTML5

Tags: html, video, streaming, live

I need to develop a web application, it needs to support IE9 as well as iPad and Android tablets. The problem I am facing is that the client is required to show live streaming video on all the pages. How can I implement live streaming video in HTML5?

Comment: Did you try anything?

For example `<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://ADR/STREAM_ADR" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> ` ?

Answer (score 2):

I recommended you to use Wowza Media Server ( Ofcourse there are several streaming servers are there. Wowza delivers video/audio with great performance and service )  I am using it for my projects. It also supports opensource players like  flow player, Jw players etc.. Install Wowza Media Server on your machine and create a live application on it and start broadcast. You need an encoder for live streaming, You can use Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder for testing. Wowza can able to broadcast the videos to iphone, Webpage, etc.,

Comment: But Wowza support only some limited browsers. and also  my client not accept to go Wowza.Is HLS Streaming will support IE9,Chrome,opera,safari,iPad and Android Tablets? i used this code its not working  <video

        src="http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"

        height="300" width="400">

    </video>

Comment: See this link: http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/hls/ to check support for HLS by various browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try the code

```
<video id="movie" width="" height="" preload controls>
   <source id="srcMp4" src="video.mp4" />
   <source id="srcOgg" src="video.ogg" />
   <object id="flowplayer" name="flowplayer" width="480" height="352" 
   data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf" 
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
     <param name="movie" 
     value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf" />
     <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
     <param name="flashvars" 
     value='config={"clip":"http://domain.com/video.flv"}' />
  </object>
</video>
```

The MP4 format is provided first, due to a previous bug in iPad which only sees the first source listed.

If the browser can't play the MP4 version, it tries to load the Ogg version. If that fails, it uses Flowplayer (flash) as a fallback.s

Comment: For live streaming video? its

Comment: Change the src to where the Video is